# Can I sort querydict in templates?

Tags: html, django

In my template I've got:

```
{% for user in users %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="info">
        <h4>{{ user.name }}</h4>
        <h5>{{ user.age }}</h5>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Usual `{% for user in users|dictsort:"user.name" %}` doesn't work as `users` is a queryset. Is there a way to display that in sorted order in the template without touching the backend?

Answer (score 1):

A [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) queryset will contain dictionaries, you can then pass this to [`dictsort`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort). Since this loops over dictionaries and not User objects you will not be able to follow foreign keys or call methods using this approach

```
{% for user in users.values|dictsort:"name" %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="info">
        <h4>{{ user.name }}</h4>
        <h5>{{ user.age }}</h5>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT: `make_list` converts the passed object to a string before making it a list so will not work. I suspect that you may be able to just pass the values queryset to `dictsort`

Comment: It doesn't work, because `make_list` does something weird and as a result I've got a list of single letters. I guess it might be something weird going on in the backend then?

Comment: @Malvinka looks like `make_list` converts to a string first so yeah won't work. I wonder if just passing the values to dictsort works?